# Run a funcion after FULLY NavigatedTo in Vue

Tags: vue.js, navigation

in this piece of code:

```
Vue.prototype.$navigateTo( MenuModule, {
        
        frame : 'basement' ,
        
        backstackVisible : true ,
        
        transition : {
            name         : "slideTop",
            duration     : 300 ,
        } 

    } )
```

how can I run a function that belongs to the `MenuModule` after the navigation is **FULLY COMPLETED** (after 300ms : duration).

I'm not looking for "setTimeout" method, cause using that seems cause some UI problems, (the animation for navigating takes sometimes a bit longer than 300ms, so I would like to detect prefect timing to run a function right after that it is **FULLY NAVIGATED** to the module).

Answer (score 0):

Use mounted() event on MenuModule to trigger the function.

Comment: it runs right after calling and mounting the module, I asking for detecting the exact time of END of the navigating animation!